# Error with Braintree UI BTDropInViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, braintree

this is my first time implementing Braintree and I've been following the documentation clearly. I've integrated it with CocoaPods but I have an issue in BTDropInViewController. It throws an error

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[UIColor bt_colorWithBytesR:G:B:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x10fd17948

In this line

```
 BTDropInViewController *dropInViewController = [[BTDropInViewController alloc]
                                                initWithAPIClient:self.braintreeClient];
```

I've tried to import these 3 headers just to be sure, but still the same result

```
#import <Braintree/UIColor+BTUI.h> 
#import "BraintreeUI.h"
#import <Braintree/BTUI.h>
```

And here is the full error

```
2016-11-16 15:56:35.418 Projc[43766:2236752] +[UIColor bt_colorWithBytesR:G:B:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x10fd17948
2016-11-16 15:56:35.504 Projc[43766:2236752] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[UIColor bt_colorWithBytesR:G:B:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x10fd17948'
*** First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001116aaf45 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000110998deb objc_exception_throw + 48
2   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001116b346d +[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
3   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000111600eea ___forwarding___ + 970
4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000111600a98 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
5   Projc                                0x000000010ccb95b0 -[BTUI borderColor] + 64
6   Projc                                0x000000010cc9abf4 -[BTDropInContentView initWithFrame:] + 964
7   UIKit                               0x000000010f0abe3d -[UIView init] + 62
8   Projc                                0x000000010ccc329e -[BTUIThemedView init] + 62
9   Projc                                0x000000010cca5fed -[BTDropInViewController initWithAPIClient:] + 285
10  Projc                                0x000000010cb0998b __51-[RegisterController basicPlanClicked]_block_invoke + 411
11  Projc                                0x000000010cac1a66 __59-[downloadJson:endPointString:WithHandler:]_block_invoke + 214
12  CFNetwork                           0x000000010d4f5b3d __75-[__NSURLSessionLocal taskForClass:request:uploadFile:bodyData:completion:]_block_invoke + 19
13  CFNetwork                           0x000000010d507fb6 __49-[__NSCFLocalSessionTask _task_onqueue_didFinish]_block_invoke + 302
14  Foundation                          0x000000011060c3b8 __NSBLOCKOPERATION_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 7
15  Foundation                          0x00000001105480e5 -[NSBlockOperation main] + 101
16  Foundation                          0x000000011052b036 -[__NSOperationInternal _start:] + 646
17  Foundation                          0x000000011052ac47 __NSOQSchedule_f + 194
18  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000111e0649b _dispatch_client_callout + 8
19  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000111dee2af _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1738
20  CoreFoundation                      0x000000011160b2e9 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
21  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001115cc8a9 __CFRunLoopRun + 2073
22  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001115cbe08 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
23  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000112291ad2 GSEventRunModal + 161
24  UIKit                               0x000000010f01f30d UIApplicationMain + 171
25  Projc                                0x000000010cba86bf main + 111
26  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000111e3b92d start + 1
27  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Comment: Are you using the correct version of the framework.

Comment: Yup, currently using the latest one. I've tried to downgrade but still having the same result